# Trying to show that the orthogonal group $O(n) \subset \mathbb{R}^{n^2}$ is closed and compact.

Tags: linear-algebra, general-topology, metric-spaces

I am currently reading Hatcher's point set topology notes. One of the exercises is this:

3.9 Consider the orthogonal group $O(n)$ consisting of all $n \times n$ orthogonal matrices, i.e., $n \times n$ matrices whose columns form an orthonormal basis $v_1,···,v_n$ for $\mathbb{R}^n$. We put a topology on $O(n)$ by regarding it as a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^{n^2}$ , taking the $n^2$ entries of a matrix in $O(n)$ as the $n^2$ coordinates of a point in $\mathbb{R}^{n^2}$ . (a) Show that $O(n)$ is a closed subset of $\mathbb{R}^{n^2}$ by considering the dot products $v_i \cdot v_j$ of the columns of matrices in $O(n)$ as functions $\mathbb{R}^{n^2} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. (b) Show that $O(n)$ is compact.

I am not too familiar with linear algebra. But, I think $O(n) = \{A = (x_1,...,x_{n^2}): AA^{T} = I\} \subset \mathbb{R}^{n^2}$.

I can construct a function $f_{ij}:\mathbb{R}^{n^2} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ where $v_i$ and $v_j$ are column vectors at the specific indices where $f_{ij}(A) = v_i \cdot v_j$. I am thinking of finding a way to show that $f_{ij}$ is continuous. I was thinking of using the function $f_{ii}$.

Comment: The map $A \to AA^T-I$ is continuous, which gives you closure. Since $\|A\| = 1$ you have boundedness.

Comment: @copper.hat As seen as a subset of $\Bbb R ^{n^2}$ with its euclidean metric (as OP apparently seems to do so), one does not have $\|A\|=1$ for $A\in O(n)$ but rather $\|A\| = \sqrt{n}$. This does not change much in the conclusion though